# $.grep filter with contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter an array with `grep` to apply CSS. My code is like below.

```
var depos = $('.panel-default > .panel-heading');
var chkd = ['ABC','XYZ'];
var found_p = $.grep(depos, function(v) {
    return jQuery.inArray(v.innerText,chkd);
});
```

The first issue is that `found_p` is not filtering the needed array values from `chkd`. After filtering it, how can I apply CSS? I tried like below but it fails

```
$(found_p[0]).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Can anybody help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your code that you're trying to find the elements that have `innerText` matching a value in the `chkd` array, you can use the `filter()` method. Try this:

```
var $depos = $('.panel-default > .panel-heading');
var chkd = ['ABC','XYZ'];
var $found_p = $depos.filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(), chkd) != -1;
});
```

The `$found_p` variable will then hold a jQuery object with all matched elements. You can apply CSS to them like this:

```
$found_p.css('background-color', 'red');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vkhrpzpr/)

However, I would suggest using CSS classes instead of adding inline styles as it is much better practice.